# How to solve the web app declaration not found

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I created a web project with net beans 11.1 and created web. XML. I didn't write anything. But the IDE prompt is wrong:

```
CVC ELT. 1. A: can't find declaration of element "web app".
```

I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question being asked is very clear, and there is no need for additional "details or clarity".

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate your problem in NetBeans 11.0, but not in NetBeans 11.2. (I don't have NetBeans 11.1 installed, so I didn't try that.)

There is a bug in NetBeans 11 which causes the error, but it seems to be fixed in NetBeans 11.2. See Bug Report NETBEANS-2398: [Netbeans 11 + web.xml = Cannot find declaration of element 'web-app'](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2398).

As a workaround [try installing NetBeans 11.2](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html) since that worked for me. You don't have to uninstall other versions of NetBeans.

To verify that the bug is fixed:

- Create a simple web application without a deployment descriptor: **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Web > Web Application**
- Select the project node in the **Projects** panel, right click and select **New > Servlet...** to run the **New Servlet** wizard.
- Do not check the checkbox labeled *Add Information to deployment descriptor (web.xml)*
- Select the project node in the **Projects** panel, right click and select **New > Other... > Web > Standard Deployment Descriptor (web.xml)**
- The newly created **web.xml** file will be opened in an edit window.
- Click anywhere in the edit window, right click and select **Validate XML** from the context menu.
- An output window labeled **Output- XML check** will be created, and show that the **web.xml** file is valid, as shown in the screen shot below:

  [image: validate web.xml]